# LateX Math Equation Multiple Alignment Issue

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

How do I correct this alignment problem?

```
\begin{align}
    & \big[ \boldsymbol{V^{2 (n)}} \big] &\begin{aligned} = \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}} \big]^{-1} \big[ \boldsymbol{\widetilde{Q}^{(n)}} \big] &- \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}} \big]^{-1} \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nm)}} \big] \big[ \boldsymbol{V^{2 (m)}} \big] \\
    &- \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}} \big]^{-1} \big[ \boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nm)}} \big] \big[ \boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (m)}} \big] - \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}} \big]^{-1} \big[ \boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nn)}} \big] \big[ \boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (n)}} \big] \\
    \end{aligned} \nonumber \\
    & &\begin{aligned}\label{eqD30} = \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}} \big]^{-1} \Big( \big[ \boldsymbol{\widetilde{Q}^{(n)}} \big] - \big[ \boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nm)}} \big] \big[ \boldsymbol{V^{2 (m)}} \big] - \big[ \boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nm)}} \big] \big[ \boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (m)}} \big] - \big[ \boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nn)}} \big] \big[ \boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (n)}} \big] \Big) \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the starting ampersand in every line.  And put the = before the begin aligned.

Comment: @JPi It did not help. The alignment is still broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an `alignat` environment you can define two alignment points. In order to allow the last line to span both, use the `\span` command.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
    \big[\boldsymbol{V^{2 (n)}}\big] &= \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}}\big]^{-1} \big[\boldsymbol{\widetilde{Q}^{(n)}}\big] &&- \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}}\big]^{-1} \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nm)}}\big] \big[\boldsymbol{V^{2 (m)}}\big]\nonumber\\
    & &&- \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}}\big]^{-1} \big[\boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nm)}}\big] \big[\boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (m)}}\big] - \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}}\big]^{-1} \big[\boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nn)}}\big] \big[\boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (n)}}\big]
    \nonumber\\
    &= \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nn)}}\big]^{-1} \Big(\big[\boldsymbol{\widetilde{Q}^{(n)}}\big] - \big[\boldsymbol{B^{\prime (nm)}}\big] \big[\boldsymbol{V^{2 (m)}}\big] - \big[\boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nm)}}\big] \big[\boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (m)}}\big] - \big[\boldsymbol{G^{\prime \prime (nn)}}\big] \big[\boldsymbol{\widetilde{\delta}^{\prime (n)}}\big]\Big) \span \span \label{eqD30}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: output]

Note the shifted equation number as the whole thing is too wide to fit the text with the default margins.

See also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115462/ignoring-specific-ampersand-formatting-on-a-specific-line-of-an-align-block) for a related question and a possible alternative solution with `\llap` or `\rlap`.

Comment: Woah so simple, it went over my head! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Nest `aligned`. Since this is just one equation, I used `split` for the outer alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % just for not getting an overfull box
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eqD30}
\begin{split}
[\bm{V}^{2 (n)}] 
  &= \begin{aligned}[t]
     [\bm{B}^{\prime (nn)}]^{-1} [\widetilde{\bm{Q}}^{(n)}] 
       &- [\bm{B}^{\prime (nn)}]^{-1} [\bm{B}^{\prime (nm)}] [\bm{V}^{2 (m)}] \\
       &- [\bm{B}^{\prime (nn)}]^{-1} [\bm{G}^{\prime \prime (nm)}] 
          [\widetilde{\bm{\delta}}^{\prime (m)}]
        - [\bm{B}^{\prime (nn)}]^{-1} [\bm{G}^{\prime \prime (nn)}]
          [\widetilde{\bm{\delta}}^{\prime (n)}]
     \end{aligned}
     \\
  &= [\bm{B}^{\prime (nn)}]^{-1}
     \bigl(
       [\widetilde{\bm{Q}}^{(n)}]
       - [\bm{B}^{\prime (nm)}] [\bm{V}^{2 (m)}]
       - [\bm{G}^{\prime \prime (nm)}] [\widetilde{\bm{\delta}}^{\prime (m)}]
       - [\bm{G}^{\prime \prime (nn)}] [\widetilde{\bm{\delta}}^{\prime (n)}]
     \bigr)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I also removed all `\big` instructions (which should be either `\bigl` or `\bigr`, however) and made bold only the base. It's better to use the `bm` package that provides `\bm` (`\boldsymbol` is turned into a synonym, but `\bm` is easier to type).

[image]

Comment: Random note: nesting `aligned` within `split` was my second idea - but I got wrong alignment of the `aligned` block relative to the `=` sign. Your image shows it correct, so I investigated: compiling with TeX Live 2016 everything looks correct, compiling on ShareLaTeX is where I saw the alignment trouble: [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mH4Ov.png) shows an overlay; red: with `alignat`, same output on ShareLaTeX and TeX Live, blue: `aligned` inside `split`, fine on TeX Live, but with broken outer alignment of the `aligned` block on ShareLaTeX as seen in the picture.

Comment: @greyshade `amsmath` had an update not too long ago fixing wrong spacing before `\begin{aligned}` (see [p. 4 in `amsmath` documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf#page=4)). This can be fixed by using `\!\begin{aligned}` for old version, as this "fix" will yield the same output with the new version as well.

Comment: @hooy thanks for pointing out the update to `aligned` in `amsmath`! You are of course correct on how to fix the issue. (And for completeness: on 2017-05-25 ShareLaTeX seems to be using TeX Live 2014 and loads `Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features` - i.e. indeed before the `v2.16a` with the change)