# xelatex + tabular: align a cell to character and skip entering that char in certain rows

Tags: tables, xetex, alignment

In my CV, I list my past (and a recent) jobs. For example:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{\emph{ – }}l | p{11cm}}
  \emph{Jun 2013} & \emph{Aug 2013} & Work position at Company\\
\end{tabular}
```

However, I worked at some companies for less than a month: for example:

```
\begin{tabular}{r@{\emph{ – }}l | p{11cm}}
  \emph{Aug 2012} \span & Other Work position at Firm\\
\end{tabular}
```

The problem with this second example is that the `\span` does not remove the alignment character (i.e. `–`) from that particular row. So the question is: **how do I remove it from selected rows?**

Comment: Hm. Where do you learned \span? Why don't you use \multicolumn? But beside this: don't show snippets, make complete examples that can be used for tests.

Comment: I’ve found `\span` in some of the answers here on StackExchange. And on snippets vs complete examples: I just thought the snippets would be enough to show you what I would like to complete.

Comment: snippets are difficult to test. You always have to add preamble and other stuff first.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306791/70043)’s the particular answer in which I’ve found the `\span`. … Next time, I include the complete striped-down examples. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\span is a low-level tex primitive. In LaTeX you should use \multicolumn to change columns styles:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\emph{ – }}l | p{11cm}}
\emph{Jun 2013} & \emph{Aug 2013} & Work position at Company\\
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\emph{Aug 2012}}& Other Work position at Firm\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to right align them in the first cell, you can use \phantom to fake the dash:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r@{\emph{~–~}}l | p{11cm}}
\emph{Jun 2013}& \emph{Aug 2013} & Work position at Company\\
\multicolumn{1}{r@{\phantom{\emph{~–~}}}}{\emph{Jul 2013}}&
& 
Other Work position at Firm\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This might more correct answer (from the _don’t-use-low-level-TeX-primitives_ point of view) and the output is exactly the same as the `\hfill` solution of @Steven B Segletes ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479289/70043)). However, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479168/xelatex-tabular-align-a-cell-to-character-and-skip-entering-that-char-in-cert#comment1210931_479289) comment of mine still applies to this answer, too.

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: I like the `\myspan` new command from the other answer, however, I can’t seem to make it work. What I tried: `\newcommand\mergecols{\def\multicolumn{1}{r@{\phantom{\mycolsep}}}{#1}}` and `\newcommand{\mergecols}[1]{\def\multicolumn{1}{r@{\phantom{\mycolsep}}}{#1}}`. … Note that I also created `\newcommand\mycolsep{~--~}`.

Comment: If you would stop to use low-level tex (in this case \def) you would have less problems. Beside this: don't ask such questions in comments. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas the `@` specification of the OP's MWE seems to be locked into stone (can't be changed on the fly), the same is not true of the `<` specification, which is re-evaluated on the fly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\mycolsep{\emph{ -- }}
\newcommand\myspan{\let\mycolsep\relax\span}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r<{\mycolsep}@{}l | p{11cm}}
  \emph{Jun 2013} & \emph{Aug 2013} & Work position at Company\\
  \emph{Aug 2012} \myspan & Other Work position at Firm\\
  \emph{Jun 2011} & \emph{Aug 2011} & Work position at Company\\
  \emph{Aug 2010} \myspan & Other Work position at Firm\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the result left-aligned, and in light of a comment by the OP, I take a slightly altered approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\mycolsep{\emph{ -- }}
\newcommand\myspan{\def\mycolsep{\phantom{\emph{ -- }}}&}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r<{\mycolsep}@{}l | p{11cm}}
  \emph{Jun 2013} & \emph{Aug 2013} & Work position at Company\\
  \emph{Aug 2012} \myspan & Other Work position at Firm\\
  \emph{Jun 2011} & \emph{Aug 2011} & Work position at Company\\
  \emph{Jul 2010} \myspan & Other Work position at Firm\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Works as expected. :)

Comment: I like the solution with `\hfill`, however, it would be nice to have the date right-aligned towards the `\mycolsep`. What I mean is that all dates are centred at the `\mycolsep`. When you use e.g. `Jul 2012`, which is a bit shorter than `Aug 2010`, you’ll see what I mean. I have no idea if it can be accomplished.

Comment: @tukusejssirs That could be tough using this approach.  Let me think some more.

Comment: @tukusejssirs Please see my edit.  I think it accomplishes what you ask.

Comment: Now it looks as I imagined it! :) … Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in a different way and with a simpler user level syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{cvpart}{}
 {
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    r
    l
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}} p{11cm}
   }
 }
 {
  \end{tabular*}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\cvrow}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{--}}m m}
 {
  \tukus_cvrow:nnn #1 { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tukus_cvrow:nnn
 {
  \emph{ \tl_trim_spaces:n { #1 } }
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \hphantom{~--~} &
   }
   {
    \mbox{~--~} & \emph{ \tl_trim_spaces:n { #2 } }
   }
  & #3 \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{cvpart}
\cvrow{Jun 2013 -- Aug 2013}{
  Work position at Company
  Work position at Company
  Work position at Company
  Work position at Company
  Work position at Company
}
\cvrow{Jul 2013}{Other Work position at Firm}
\end{cvpart}

\end{document}
```

The `\cvrow` command takes two arguments; if the first argument contains `--`, one branch is followed and the en-dash is printed. Otherwise just the space is allocated.

Adjust the 11cm to suit your text width.

[image]